# Checking Browser Support for specific Code

Tags: javascript, fallback, browser-support

I'm trying to find a way to scan through my code to tell me when different properties were first supported in different browsers. Of course I could use Modernizr for everything or manually go through the entire code, checking browser support for methods and properties. I was just wondering if there was an easier way to earn knowledge of which methods and properties I should provide fallbacks for.

If I have this:

```js
document.getElementById('pressThisNow').addEventListener("click", function(e){
     console.log("e.target: " + e.target);
     console.log("e.toElement: " + e.toElement);
     console.log("e.relatedTarget: " + e.relatedTarget);
    }, false);
```

```html
<h1 id="pressThisNow">Press with console open</h1>
```

It should tell me that

- getElementById support for chrome began [version], Firefox: [v],
  IE:[v]...
- addEventListener support for chrome began [version], Firefox: [v],
  IE:[v]...
- target support for chrome began [version], Firefox: [v], IE:[v]...
- toElement support for chrome began [version], Firefox: [v], IE:[v]...
- relatedTarget support for chrome began [version], Firefox: [v],
  IE:[v]...
- Probably for console.log too

Comment: There is no such information in the javascript, you can just know if the properties are defined or not when you execute it. The only way would be to execute your javascript on all versions of all browser and gather the result. But it probably doesn't worth it

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? I think your application should have browser requirements. [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) is a good resource whether a browser supports a feature from what version.

Comment: Yes, unfortunate when it doesn't contain information about .toElement and .relatedTarget, there are other sources though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Modernizr is one of the best, also there are few other websites which can help you to track this. Adding list below, hope this will help to check which suites you best.

1. http://tutti.tobyho.com/
2. Modernizr - https://modernizr.com
3. JSDO.it - http://jsdo.it/
4. QuirkMode - http://www.quirksmode.org/

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if these help.